# Objective C: How to set the subview display in the current visible frame? (UITableView)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, addsubview

I have a UITableViewController and intend to add a subview to it when I click a button i.e. refresh button. My code is as follows:

```
//set up loading page
self.myLoadingPage = [[LoadingPageViewController alloc]init ];
self.myLoadingPage.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
self.myLoadingPage.view.hidden = NO;

[self.view addSubview:self.myLoadingPage.view];
```

My question is how can I set this subview to be in the current visible frame? especially for a UITableviewcontroller where I might click on the refresh button after scrolling down to the 100th cell, for this example, my subview will still be added right at the top of the table view (starting from cell 1). Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the lines around so that you set the frame after you made it a subview

```
self.myLoadingPage = [[LoadingPageViewController alloc]init ];
self.myLoadingPage.view.hidden = NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.myLoadingPage.view];
self.myLoadingPage.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

Comment: thanks for your response! That works, but I have 1 more challenges. First, I can still scroll my UITableview, and the subview will not be fixed in the frame as I scroll. I tried to set the userInteractionEnabled property to NO, but when I click on the refresh button while the table is 'decelarating" from a scroll, the subview might only show exactly on screen, i.e. half of it might be outside the visible screen due to the scroll. Any tips on how to handle this?